# How to build Kazoo RPM files from source code?

Tags: rpm, specifications, kazoo

I am experimenting with kazoo and wanted to install it from source code. I am able to generate a deployable release but i am not able to build rpm from it. I heard that spec file is needed to build rpm but couldn't generate one . Any help is appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please don't ask the same question on different site. Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1467706/how-to-build-kazoo-rpm-files-from-source-code

Comment: Sorry i couldn't figure out the category in which it is to be placed. That's why i placed the question in both sites.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question. First, read something about packaging: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/ Then, you can use this wizard: https://xsuchy.github.io/rpm-spec-wizard/#